# htmlPurifier not working with TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, xss, htmlpurifier

I´m using htmlPurifier to prevent XSS Attacks from users and everything works ok on input type="text" fields. But, when i try to clean tinyMCE textareas seems like htmlPurifier don´t work, ex.:

**Simple input text field**

Input.:

```
<script>alert("XSS")</script>Cleaning Test
```

Output: Cleaning Test

**tinyMCE TEXTAREA**

Input.:

```
<script>alert("XSS")</script>
```

Output: `<script>alert("XSS")</script>`

Did i miss something ? Why htmlPurifier work on a simple input text and with tinyMCE textarea don´t ?

Ps.: Magic Quotes are Off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think i found what was wrong.

tinyMCE automatically encode entities such:

```
< into &lt;
> into &gt;
" into &quot;
& into &amp;
```

I tried to use diferent types of entity_encoding on tinyMCE but none of them seems to work as i want, so i used PHP: html_entity_decode to decode tinyMCE text area and then i used htmlPurifier to sanitize the data and everything works ok now.

Hope someone else find this usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `tinymce.triggerSave()` in order to write the tinymce content back to the tinymce source element (can be a textarea) before the purifier can work.

Comment: I have tried tinyMCE.triggerSave() with no success either... I´ve made my submit button call triggerSave function onClick (Same Results) and i´ve tried to submit the form using JavaScript like: document.formname.submit(); after tinyMCE.triggerSave() (Same Results). I really don´t know what more i could try...